# Multi line find (grapping) and replace text in XML file using perl

Tags: regex, perl

Here i am trying to find and replace text content in one XML file using perl regular expression.

Sample  XML Code:

```
<root>
<add>
<st>xxxx</st>
<pin>xxx</pin>
</add>
</root>
```

Now i want to find / grep text from `<add>` to `</add>` and replace `<xyz>`xxx`</xyz>`

```
<add>
<st>xxxx</st>
<pin>xxx</pin>
</add>
```

Note:

if above content are in single line i mean without line break in between `<add>` to `</add>`, as `<add><st>xxxx</st><pin>xxx</pin></add>` i can use `<add>(.*)<\/add>` to find / grep.

---

Thanking You

Thirusanguraja V

Comment: why do you want to solve this with regex?? i think its easy to import the xml to an hash (maybe with `XML::Simple` and then export it to xml as well ?

Comment: Your before and after does not match what you say you want to do.

Comment: There's no `<xyz>xxx</xyz>` to replace in your example. Could you give a relevant example, please?

Comment: You need to clarify your question.  Please give an example of what the input looks like and what your desired output looks like.  Even better would be adding a code sample showing what you've tried so far.

Comment: Hi everybody, i am have one text file with xml/HTML tags like `<p>Some text content</p>` and i am using perl code like `perl -pi -i.bak -e "s/<p>(.*)<\/p>/<para>Some new text<\/para>/g" label.aspx` to find and replace, Those above code is working fine when the `<p>` to `</p>` text content are in single line without line break in between `<p>` to `</p>`, if `\n` new line or line break character present in between `<p>` to `</p>` those code is not working. Because this perl code is reading document content as line by line i think so, but i want find the text over multiple line in the document.

Answer (score 0):

Using [XML::XSH2](http://p3rl.org/XML%3a%3aXSH2), a wrapper around [XML::LibXML](http://p3rl.org/XML%3a%3aLibXML):

```
open input.xml ;
$add = /root/add ;
delete $add/* ;
insert element xyz into $add ;
insert text 'xxx' into $add/xyz ;
save :b ;
```

Comment: Its ok. But i want to read that xml file in text mode and i want to use regexp to perform those function, so please try to understand me.

Comment: Just consider given sample code as raw text and do the find and replae.